# Do different resistances stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage-resistance

EDIT2: I just looked up the oath online, and it seems the confusion has been caused by a loss in translation. The wording in my copy did not speak of "granting resistance to damage from spells" but it said "taking half damage from spells" which is pretty close to the wording if you succeed in your saving throw against a fireball.
So this question is indeed a duplicate and can be closed and forgotten.

I know that stacking the same resistance accomplishes nothing.
But what happens when different resistances affect the same damage event?

Let's say the random evil warlock Doomdoom shoots a fireball at the bear totem barbarian Fuzzyface who is raging through his minions.
But Fuzzyface is standing right next to Evl-b-gon who is a paladin that took the oath of the ancients.

Bear totem halves damage(=grants resistance) from pretty much all damage types, including fire. Which a fireball undoubtedly would deal.
The oath of the ancients aura does the same for spell damage. The fireball is without a doubt also a spell.

So, how much damage does Fuzzyface take?
RAW preferred, but RAI with an argument about why it is intended that way would be appreaciated as well.

EDIT: Apparently this is taken as a duplicate by a lot of people. While pretty similar, I do not think those questions ask the same thing.

There is no damage type "spell" in the game.
The barbarian has resistance to the damage type,
but the Paladin halves damage from a ***source***.
Solving this with PHB 197 by accepting "spell" as a damagetype would effectively remove the benefit of the bear, since the damage types he gains resistances to will be almost always be caused by a spell.

Comment: @firedraco frankly I do not know: Personally I do not think so, because the barbarian has a resistance to a damage TYPE, while the aura grants resistance to a damage SOURCE. But that may be the programmer in me speaking and "normal" people might view it differently

Comment: The first paragraph, yeah that is a _very_ important distinction in the wording. If the feature had read "taking half damage from spells", it would have stacked with Resistances, similar to how you can succeed in a saving throw to take half damage, and then apply resistance, or a raging barb-rogue using uncanny dodge and then further decreasing the damage with resistance.

Comment: Both features in question provide resistance, and being resistant more than once to the same damage doesn't stack; the fourth paragraph on p. 197 of the PHB seems very clear on this. I agree that this is fundamentally a duplicate.

Comment: @Marq Yes, it is. I didn't explain the issue very skillfully, but daze413 and my EDIT2 should clear up what the original issue was. Basically my RAW was different from everyone elses caused by a translation mistake.

Comment: OK, cool. Here's a tip for future questions: There's no need to mark your edits in the question, since there's a full edit history available for anyone to see. The goal of the site is to cultivate good questions and good answers, so it's better long-term if you just edit your question to read clearly, even if that involves significant changes.

Comment: Yes, [please don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Your post should ideally at all times look like the final version, or like there simply were no other revisions -- you wouldn't want a Wikipedia article or a textbook to be full of "edit:" amendments, would you? Same goes for us reading your post. Iron over it a bit to finalise it.

Comment: @doppelgreener I get your point, but would I then omit what caused the confusion or put it on top or below the original question?

Comment: Ah, I just saw your acknowledgement it was caused by a mistranslation or something like that. There's probably no action you need to take in this case.